# How do I check generalization (validation loss) on google object detection?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

When I train ssd_inception_v2 model, as below process, that message "global step~ loss ~" is showed on command screen. is the loss validation loss?
In addition, like below second image that shows a various type of loss, I couldn't know whether the loss is training loss or validation loss.
How could I check the validation loss of my training model??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF9Qn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kOYe.png)